# Using Token in an application as asset

Tags: erc-20, tokens, mint

There is a smart contract deployed on ethereum network, which is an ERC-20 standard token

We want to use this token in an application as a virtual currency, for example users can buy it via fiat and use it inside the application, and also they should be able to withdraw the token and convert it to real money

The Token has an initial supply, let's say minted to the owner account

The question is, what should be done when user buy a token via fiat? should we integrate with the contract and transfer from the owner account to the receiver (user) account?
And probably transfer from user to owner account when user withdraw the token?

Should we Transfer from supply? or should Mint a new amount on token?

and how it impact on liquidity and the price of the token in market?